# Template Literal Tag Function with variable?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

Is it possible for a variable that has been assigned the value of a template literal to be passed to a function, and then that function calls it with a function?

Example:

```
function strLiteralProcessor(str){
     console.log(str);
     return //what goes here? I want to call the tag function myTagFunc with str, but myTagFuncstr is obviously wrong.
};

var name = prompt("What's your name?");
strLiteralProcessor(`Hi, ${name}!`);
```

Do I do something like `myTagFunc(str)` or am I missing something?

Comment: You can only call a tag function when the template literal is used. After that it's just a string.

Comment: What is `myTagFunc`? Not certain what expected result is?